# conda appears to dump all environments in the same directroy

Tags: ubuntu, conda

I've recently installed conda on my wsl. I'm not sure how this is supposed to work but I'm entertaining an idea that it's not maintaining the virtual environments as it's supposed to and instead is dumping all packages into the same directory for all environments. For example I create a new environment openai_test and activate it using:

```
(base) conda activate openai_test
```

Next I try to install openai:

```
(openai_test) pip install openai
```

And I get:

```
(openai_test) pip install openai
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: openai in ./lib/python3.11/site-packages (0.27.9)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.20 in ./lib/python3.11/site-packages (from openai) (2.31.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in ./lib/python3.11/site-packages (from openai) (4.65.0)
Requirement already satisfied: aiohttp in ./lib/python3.11/site-packages (from openai) (3.8.4)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in ./lib/python3.11/site-packages (from requests>=2.20->openai) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in ./lib/python3.11/site-packages (from requests>=2.20->opena
...
```

Also:

```
(openai_test) $ which pip
/home/<user-name>/.local/bin/pip
```

Shouldn't the pip command be pulled from the conda directory? Is my environment messed up?

Comment: Did you install Python and Pip in the environment first? (new environments are empty) Also, some terminals (e.g., tmux) can mess with PATH such that the Conda environment’s bin is not prioritized.